# Hacer una query ignorando las tildes en Mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Estoy buscando la forma de usar el método find() para encontrar todos los documentos de la colección que contengan una query introducida por el ususario. El problema es que, si el usuario introduce un término de busqueda sin tilde, no se encuentra el documento.

Por ejemplo: si el usuario escribe "sandia" en vez de "sandía", ya no le aparecerá el documento en cuestión.

Se me ha ocurrido recorrer todos los documentos de la colección y añadirles un campo extra que sea el nombre, pero sin tildes. Pero, antes de ponerme a ello, me gustaría saber si existe un método más simple. He buscado en Google y en SOes y no ha habido manera.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: quizas una busqueda usando collation te funcionaría, pero el problema es que solo serviría para busquedas completas, es decir, si buscas "sandia" te la encontraría, pero si buscas "sandi" no la encontraría. Te serviría?
Otra opcion podría ser usando un indice de tipo "text" y usando full text search, pero tendrías el mismo problema, que no encontrarías coincidencias parciales, solo completas.

Comment: @pipe ¡Muchas gracias, investigaré! Supongo con lo del collation me funcionará. Es para buscar nombres de artistas. No me imagino a nadie buscano Rosali, en vez de Rosalia jeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te sirve el `collation`, lo podrías hacer así:

```
db.collection.find({key: 'sandia'}).collation({"locale" : "es", "strength" : 1});
```

Eso te debería devolver el documento con key `sandía` o `Sandía` o `sandia` o `Sandia`

Saludos